# Removing padding from skimage's try_all_threshold matplotlib figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, scikit-image

I'm trying to automatically save the figure generated by scikit-image's `try_all_threshold`.

MWE:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import sys
import os
from pathlib import Path
import numpy
import skimage
from skimage import color, filters, io
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

skimage.io.use_plugin("pil")

mpl.rcParams["font.family"] = ["sans-serif"]
mpl.rcParams["font.sans-serif"] = ["Linux Biolinum"]
mpl.rcParams["axes.titlesize"] = "medium"

def analyze(files):

    for index, file in enumerate(files):
        print("Analyzing {0}, please wait...".format(file))

        try:
            image = io.imread(file)
        except ValueError as error:
            print("Error when loading image, skipping: {0}".format(error))
            continue

        luma = color.rgb2gray(image)

        # Threshold the image to obtain the reference borders
        fig, ax = filters.try_all_threshold(
            luma, figsize=(1, 2), verbose=False)
        plt.show()

        fig.savefig("test.png")

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        files = [path for path in sys.argv[1:] if Path(path).exists()]

    if len(files) == 0:
        print("No images to slice.")
    else:
        print("Found {0} images to slice.".format(len(files)))
        analyze(files)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The output contains a lot of padding, which I have to remove:

[image]

I've tried using `bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0` as suggested in other answers but to no effect.

What's missing for matplotlib to remove all the padding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change `figsize` to match the aspect ratio of the image you're trying to set. `try_all_threshold` will make a grid of shape `(4, 2)` to fill your input figure size. If your image is mostly horizontal, this gives a lot of white space in the vertical dimension. With `figsize=(6, 5)` I got a decent result with your image:

[image]

(**Edit:** `figsize=` is given as (width, height) in inches.)